# Using jQuery to remove multiple textarea boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am still very new to JavaScript and jQuery.

I have the jQuery "add boxes" functionality working for adding dynamic `<textarea>`s, but the remove portion does not work.

**My code:**

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('textarea').size() + 1;
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $('.this:last').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });

    $('.Add').live('click', function(e) {
        $('<div><textarea id="txt"></textarea> <textarea id="txt2"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');

        i++;
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dnwTV/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's another option: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/dnwTV/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `.this:last`, and no elements with a `class` of `this` exists. Use `textarea:last` as a selector instead. Also, your markup is inconsistent; the original should have another `<div>` wrapping the two `<textarea>`s. [Here is a corrected version of your jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dnwTV/6/)

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('.Option > div').size() + 1;

    $('#remove').click(function(e) {
        if (i > 1) {
            $('.Option > :last').remove();
            i--;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.Add').click(function(e) {
        $('<div><textarea id="txt"></textarea> <textarea id="txt2"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');

        i++;
    });
});​
```

**That said**, I don't believe your current code is either sufficiently neat or generic. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnwTV/15/) for an example of how you might make this cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! The alternative jsFiddle you linked at the bottom is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

#### Note

You're creating multiple `textarea` with same `id`. It is not allowed.

You can change your add code like following:

```
    $('.Add').live('click', function(e) {
        $('<div><textarea id="txt'+ i +'"></textarea> <textarea id="txt'+ (i+1) +'"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');
        i++;
    });
```

#### And one more thing

Instead of `live`, use `on()`. As you're not adding `.Add` dynamically so you not need `live` delegation for that. Just use following:

```
$('.Add').on('click', function(e) {
     $('<div><textarea id="txt"></textarea> <textarea id="txt2"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');    
     i++;
});
```

#### Your complete code should look like:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('textarea').size() + 1;
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        i = $('textarea').size() + 1;
        if (i > 1) {
            $('.Option > textarea:last').last().remove();
            i--;
        }
    });

    $('.Add').on('click', function(e) {
        $('<textarea id="txt' + i + '"></textarea> <textarea id="txt' + (i + 1) + '"></textarea>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');
        i++;
    });
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dnwTV/20/)**

Comment: an alternative for multiple textarea with same id?

Answer (score 0):

here's an updated fiddle that works

http://jsfiddle.net/dnwTV/5/

**Javascript**:

```
$(function() {

    $('#remove').click(function() {
        $('.Option div:last').remove();                
    });

    $('.Add').live('click', function(e) {
        var i = $('textarea').length + 1;
        $('<div><textarea id="txt' + i + '"></textarea> <textarea id="txt' + (i+1) + '"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');
    });
});​
```

Also fixed the fact that you're reusing html `id`'s which should be unique per page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the effect that you are trying to achieve:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/dnwTV/4/

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class='Option'><textarea id="txt"></textarea> <textarea id="txt2"></textarea> </div>
<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>

<br/><br/>
<span class='Add'>Add Option</span>
```

​jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('textarea').size() + 1;
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $('textarea:last').parent().remove();
            i--;
        }
    });

    $('.Add').click(function(){
        $('<div><textarea id="txt"></textarea> <textarea id="txt2"></textarea></div>').fadeIn('fast').appendTo('.Option');

        i++;
    });

});​
```